# Tomcat keeps overwriting server.xml

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Whenever I update server.xml after a period of time tomcat overwrites it with the default text in the file. When it overwrites the seems to be random. Is there a config option I need to add to prevent this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this use server location as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @JustinKSU screenshot/screenshot snippet in answer ?

Comment: imgur.com is blocked at my work.  That's why I didn't see it.  Thanks.

Comment: @JustinKSU that should'nt make any difference? are uploaded images not hosted on the stackoverflow site itself ?

Comment: Even if it is hosted on a stackoverflow server, if I can't hit imgur.com to do the translation, then I can't see the image.  I'm at home now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Option 1 and 3 will prevent overwriting your Tomcat config, but you lose the management console.  Is there a way to have the best of both worlds?

Comment: @JustinKSU Note the message "Server must be published with no modules present to make changes."  : Remove all apps from your server installation and then re-plublish, you should then be able to make changes.